# How can I remove the default top margin on a pdf document with itextsharp?

Tags: itext, margin

I´m trying to get my pdf document to start at (0,0) however it seems that the document object has a default top margin which I cannot set to 0.
Is there a way to do this?

My code looks like the following

```
        using (MemoryStream memoria = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document pdf = new Document(new Rectangle(288, 144));

            try
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdf, memoria);

                pdf.Open();
                pdf.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

                PdfPTable tPrincipal = new PdfPTable(2);            
                tPrincipal .WidthPercentage = 100;           
                tPrincipal .DefaultCell.Border = 0;
                tPrincipal .TotalWidth = 288f;
                tPrincipal .LockedWidth = true;
```

....

I just can´t get to set the top margin to 0. It just doesnt care about my setting to (0,0,0,0) and leaves a top margin (around 50f).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll need to set your margins in your Document constructor, like this:

```
Document pdf = new Document(new Rectangle(288f, 144f), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

You won't need to use the `Document.SetMargins()` method.  I believe you'd use `SetMargins()`after you create a new page by calling `Document.NewPage()`.

Comment: Thanks Jay that did work, however I had to include the "f" after all ceros. Document pdf = new Document(new Rectangle(288f, 144f), 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

Comment: and there is no error when you use 0, it just puts in the default margins. 0f All the way!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.setMargins(0 , 0 , 0 , 0);
```

**Option 2:**

```
Document pdf = new Document(new Rectangle(595 , 842 ), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Where, 595x842 is A4 size paper.

Answer (score 0):

I did like below where “…/XYZ.pdf” is the path to generated pdf file download path.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter(“…/XYZ.pdf”));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
doc.setMargins(0f , 0f , 0f , 0f);
```

Comment: The problem of the question is specific to iText versions before 7. Your code is iText 7 code, though.